# How to test model class using junit to cover field validations?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mocking, junit5

I am writing unit test cases using junit and mockito for my spring boot application. Now, I also want to write test cases for request model class to achieve minimum 90% code coverage as per business requirement.

**There are 3 fields in request model class like id, revision and state. Example: If id field in request body is null or empty or length is less then 8 than it should give error like Id should not be null and Id size should be 8.**

Request model class code is as below.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Request {

    @NotNull(message = "{request.id.notNull}")
    @Size(min=8, max=8, message = "{request.id.size}")
    @Schema(type = "string", example="X1234567")
    private String id;
    
    @NotNull(message = "{request.revision.notNull}")
    @Schema(type = "integer", example="0")
    private Integer revision;
    
    @NotNull(message = "{request.state.notNull}")
    @Size(min=2,max=2,  message = "{request.state.size}")
    @Pattern(regexp="^(BB|Bb|bB|bb|MM|Mm|mM|mm)$", message= "{request.state.pattern}")
    @Schema(type = "string", example="BB", allowableValues = {"BB","Bb", "bB", "bb", "MM", "Mm", "mM", "mm"})
    private String state;
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder details = new StringBuilder();
        details.append("Id:"+this.id);
        details.append(" revision:"+this.revision);
        details.append(" state:"+this.state);
        return details.toString();
    }

}
```

**How to write test case for it or how can validate in unit testing  and also want to cover toString() method in unit testing ?**

Answer (score 1):

To test the validation you start the web layer and send some requests with a body that has some errors, just so you test your backend validation. Read more about MockMvc here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

Alternatively, you can test it without starting the Spring context, simply by using a default validator, like this:

```java
@Test
void testNullId() {
    Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

    Request req = new Request(null, 123, "BB");
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Request>> result = validator.validate(req);

    assertThat(result).hasSize(1);
    var violation = result.iterator().next();
    assertThat(violation.getMessage()).isEqualTo("{request.id.notNull}");
}
```

This will allow you to create faster tests and get the feedback quickly. For instance, you can write `@ParameterizedTest`s where you'll specify combinations of inout (request payload) and expected output (constraint violation messages).

For `toString()` simply callhe method and assert on the String returned:

```java
@Test
void testToString() {
    Request req = new Request("aaa", 123, "BB");

    assertThat(req.toString()).isEqualTo("Id:aaa revision:123 state:BB");
}
```